# What are advantages or disadvantages of Animate versus Animator

Tags: animation

I am curious what are advantages/disadvantages of using Animator instead of the Animate? Why and for what purpose the Animator has been introduced?

Who knows?

To address the question of @Kuba:
There is the classical situation of making animation:

```
Animate[expression, {parameter, lowerLimit, higherLimit}]
```

There is another way:

```
Manipulate[expression, {parameter, lowerLimit, higherLimit, ControlType->Animator}]
```

Comment: Ah, so it is `Animate` vs `Manipulate`+`ControlType->Animator`.

Comment: I find that `Manipulate` gives far greater freedom in mixing control types (sliders with buttons with pull-downs, etc.).  It is extremely difficult to do that with simple `Animate`.

Comment: `Animate` is simply constructs a `Manipulate` with an `Animator`, which is convenient for that narrow class of applications.  See the output of `Animate[x, {x, 0, 1}] // InputForm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great application I've used `Animator` for, is an animation in time while also being able to manipulate other variables simultaneously.

For instance

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {
   {Thickness[.006], Circle[{0, 0}, r]},
   {PointSize[.03], Red, Point[r {Cos@#, Sin@#} &@t]}
   },
  PlotRange -> 2
  ],
 {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], Animator},
 {r, 1, 2}
 ]
```

[image]

Here we have a constantly moving point while still being able to manipulate the radius of the circle. (Granted the gif is doesn't *exactly* represent this since it was made with `Table`, but you get the idea)

Whereas, if this was done with `Animate`, all variables would evolve at the same time.